# What is the easiest way (user experience wise) to get xpub?

Tags: wallet, address, public-key, address-generation, hardware-wallet

I'v got monitoring app going for my hardware wallet and am planning to release it to public. Biggest pain point right now is asking users to enter their xpub key. It can be done, but there is no decent documentation online and every big hardware wallet company has their own explanation in FAQ.

I'm trying to figure out if there is an easier more unified way to access xpub address be it for ledger nano s, trezor, keep key or any other wallet?

Comment: It sound like you want to identify mechanisms to query each hardware wallet for xpubs for a particular account with minimal enduser involvement or experience. Is this the objective? Each Bitcoin derived altcoin has its own flavor of an xpub that is detached.

Comment: @skaht pretty much, I was hoping for a solution that will not require much user traction, nor need to connect hardware wallets. Given choice of bitcoin chain, lets say BTC and public address example, is it possible to reverse engineer / query for xpub either in algo or using third party api?